# Directives scopes and inheritance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Could someone explain to me, why with the following code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>   

<body>
   <div ng-controller="myController"> 
       {{message}}
    <div ng-if=true>
        {{message}}
        <div outer   style="background:yellow;padding:20px">
            {{message}}    
        </div>
    </div>  

   </div>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp',[])
   .controller('myController', function ($scope,$rootScope){   
       $scope.message="Football game";
   })
   .directive('outer',  function() {
            return {  

               scope: {}, 
               link:{
                   post:function(scope,element){ 
                       scope.message="Basketball.game";                                           
                    }
               }
            }

    });
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting for all instances of {{message}} `Football Game`? I would expect the last one to be `Basketball Game` since at first, compiler is searching inside outer's directive scope and it can find property named `message` with `Basketball Game` as value. Why it does not use that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the last message is evaluated in the scope of myController and not as you expect in the directives scope. It's unknown the the directive scope because you made a isolated scope with `scope: {}`, if you set `scope: true`, it will do as you think because it'll act as a child scope.

**Working with isolated scope**

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>   

<body>
   <div ng-controller="myController"> 
       {{message}}
    <div ng-if=true>
        {{message}}
        <div outer   style="background:yellow;padding:20px">
            {{message}}    
        </div>
    </div>  

   </div>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp',[])
   .controller('myController', function ($scope,$rootScope){   
       $scope.message="Football game";
   })
   .directive('outer',  function() {
            return {  

               scope: {}, 
               link:{
                   post:function(scope,element){ 
                       scope.message="Basketball.game";                                           
                    }
               },
               template: "<div>This is directive {{message}}</div>",
               
            }
    });
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

**Working with child scope**

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>   

<body>
   <div ng-controller="myController"> 
       {{message}}
    <div ng-if=true>
        {{message}}
        <div outer   style="background:yellow;padding:20px">
            {{message}}    
        </div>
    </div>  

   </div>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp',[])
   .controller('myController', function ($scope,$rootScope){   
       $scope.message="Football game";
   })
   .directive('outer',  function() {
            return {  

               scope: true, 
               link:{
                   post:function(scope,element){ 
                       scope.message="Basketball.game";                                           
                    }
               },

            }

    });
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```